# asp inline databound not calling method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so in my page i need an Asp:DropDownList that only shows up if the query string is a certain status.

my asp document is like this

```
<asp:content ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" 
                  ID="FiscalYearHistoryYearsDropDown"  
                  Visible='<%# Me.IsHistoryPage()%>'>

</asp:DropDownList>

<!-- Some other markup -->

</asp:content>
```

and i have a backend method

```
Public Function IsHistoryPage() As Boolean

    Dim IsHistory As Boolean = False

    If Me.TransactionStatus = Enumerations.TransactionStatus.Posted Then
        IsHistory = True
    End If

    Return IsHistory

End Function
```

i put a breakpoint inside the method and it is never called. 
I tried making the inline asp <%= but that didn't work. i tried single quotes and double quotes. but that didn't seem to work either.  i also tried an inline IIF() block instead of a method call.

The thing is when I use a  <%# it doesn't complain, and it loads the page. it is just always true.

when i use a <% or <%= it throws the yellow page of death.

Answer (score 0):

`<%# %>` is for data binding context. It should be used when you want to get some data inside the data bound control, usually in template of some sort. Even though DropDownList is a data-bound control, it is not being used inside one, so `%#` is not an option

`<%= %>` is an equivalent to `Response.Write`, so it outputs a plain markup and therefore cannot be used to set server-side control properties.

`<% %>` does not output anything anywhere, to the best of my knowledge.

The reason `%#` and `%=` exist is to give developers an ability to create some interaction between code behind and markup in cases when it is not trivial thing to do so. Your case is different, since you can just run this somewhere in Page_Load or Page_PreRender:

```
FiscalYearHistoryYearsDropDown.Visible = IsHistoryPage()
```